# greping and replacing 2 file paths

Tags: linux, unix, grep, cygwin

I am currently working on a project where I would like to change a picture in multiple places.

```
  old file dir: /images/icons/helpPop.png
  new file dir: /public/website_pngs/icons-buttons/button_question_mark.png
```

I want to try

```
grep -rl 'images/icons/helpPop' . | xargs sed -i 's/images/icons/helpPop/public/website_pngs/icons-buttons/button_question_mark/g'
```

But I know that will not work.  I am looking into delimiters and would like some extra advice please.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do—do you want to move the file from the old location to the new location, or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in grep -rl 'images/icons/helpPop' . ; do cp $i $i.bak; sed -i 's/images\/icons\/helpPop/public\/website_pngs\/icons-buttons\/button_question_mark/g' < $i.bak > $i; done
```

Comment: that /g at the end is not the file name.  Will that change?

Comment: That /g means "replace every instance of the string"; otherwise it'll just replace the first instance and then go to the next file.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking into delimiters and would like some extra advice please.

some suggestions:

- if the old/new dirs are fixed, try to save them into variables
- use different delimiter in sed e.g. `"s#$old#$new#g" or "s@$old@$new@g"` (double quotes!!)
- to be safer, you better escape the `. (period/dot)` in your old dir text. since it indicates `any char` in regex. it **could** be a dangerous operation with plain text like that. (fortunately you don't have `.*` in your path ^_^  )

or you want the working codes?

**EDIT** for comment:

you don't need to "setup" the delimiter, just use it, like you are using `/`, take a look this example:

```
kent$  echo "/////"|sed 's#/#?#g'
?????

kent$  echo "/////"|sed 's^/^?^g'
?????

kent$  echo "/////"|sed 's%/%?%g'
?????

kent$  echo "/////"|sed 's;/;?;g'
?????
```

Comment: would more like to know how to use/set up a delimiter

Comment: i am having an issue with this bc i do not have sed on cygwin

Comment: @SariRahal you don't have sed available? then why are you asking `sed` solution??